# Candy Cane Style Symbology (Christmas)

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, line

I try to make a *candy cane* style for a line geometry with QGIS
I used the hatching and line symbology but the hach are squared.

Have you one better idea to do:

- a more smooth and rounded symbology
- the hatches limited by the line itself

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

The symbol is from multiple parts:

1. A white 5mm Simple Line as base, using a round join style.
   [image]
2. On top of that: A Hashed Line using an interval of 6mm and a hash length of 3mm which is  drawing a red 3mm Simple Line, using a round cap style.
   [image]
3. On top of that: The same configuration for a Hashed Line but in white
   [image]
4. On the whole layer level (under Layer Rendering) a Draw Effect: Inner Glow with a spread of 0.3mm and a blur radius of 1mm using a dark grey color.
   [image]

It's a bit blotchy but transports the idea well enough in my opinion. I hope you like it!

Comment: at step 3, you should add an offset of 3 mm to show the same as on the picture

Comment: With the new group blending possibilities in QGIS 3.24+ one could probably put the inner glow on a separate layer and cut the sides and corners of the cane more nicely.

Comment: Could you add an exemple?